# How to layer Components and Graphics

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I wanted to add depth to my game menu, and was wondering if I draw an image, a component and finally another image on top i.e multiple layers.

I want to do this through a JPanel, here is the code I managed to come up with

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Main {

    private HashMap<String, Integer> componentLayer = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel() {

        BufferedImage buffer = new BufferedImage(800, 600, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g1) {

            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) buffer.getGraphics();

            // DRAW LAYER 1
            
            try {
                g.drawImage(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("image path")), 0, 0, 925, 925, null);
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // DRAW LAYER 2
            // DRAW LAYER 3 and so on

            g1.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, null);
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Main());
    }

    public Main() {
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.add(panel);
    }
}
```

The HashMap contains the component name, and the layer it is assigned to. Graphics are drawn as needed in between these, which means graphics are not assigned to specific layers only the components are.

Comment: You've already set up a basic structure for layered drawing with your `paintComponent` method. You could simply continue drawing additional layers.

Comment: You can draw multiple layers using only images (no components) if and only if each image has transparent pixels that allow the lower layers to show through the upper layers.

Comment: @Daqs how do I draw the components using their name?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc im trying to have working JButtons, with a short part of it covered by an image (giving it the depth effect I am talking about), and underneath this button there are going to be more images.

Comment: You don't mix component `JPanels` with drawing `JPanels`.  Period.

Comment: check out JLayeredPane. I think this is what you want

Comment: You might want to wrap each JButton in a decorating [JLayer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JLayer.html).

Comment: 1) The only time you use the getGraphics() method of the BufferedImage is when you want to paint onto the Buffered image. So you would not have that kind of logic in a painting method. The BufferedImage would be created and painted onto externally to the painting method. 2) To paint the BufferedImage on the panel (or for other custom painting) you use the Graphics object passed to the paintComponent(...) method. 3) Never do I/O in a painting method. This will impact performance if you read the image every time you paint it.

Comment: *how do I draw the components using their name?* - you don't. Swing will paint the component based on the component hierarchy in the frame. *part of it covered by an image ... and underneath this button there are going to be more images.* - not sure what you want. Do you have an image showing what you want? If you want the JLayer, I would start with the Swing tutorial on [How to Decorate Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html). Your question needs clarification. You have answers suggesting: a) custom painting b) JLayeredPane c) JLayer.

Comment: paintComponent can be called whenever Swing thinks the image needs to be redrawn. Do not load it from disk or resources - it needs to be in memory already.